# Apache not responding while server is online

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, not-responding

Since a hour, apache stopped responding. I can reach the server with putty and the average load is only a few percent. Apache is (re)starting without error. If it helps: this morning the server turned itself magically off but in this case it's still on, it worked all day without any further problems.

I have absolutely no idea what to look/search for :(

Comment: Servers don't turn themselves off "magically".

Comment: I know, it probably crashed

Comment: So take a look in /var/log/httpd or /var/log/apache2 or similar and see what the error logs show.

Comment: You don't need a Q&A site you need education and a consultant.

Comment: I encountered a problem with SELinux.   This can cause apache not to work after it has been installed.  You have to configure it correctly for the enabling of web serving.

Answer (score 2):

If it were me I'd....

- start with top - always the first place to look when things are amiss - is the load average too high? Too low?
- next, netstat -nap | less - is the webserver listening on the relevant ports?
- if apache is running, then check the webserver logs - is any traffic going through? Anny errors logged?
- then the messages log - is the firewall blocking traffic? Is there anything else amiss?

> this morning the server turned itself magically off

Does the error log show it being shutdown? If not, does the messages log show the oom killer terminating processes?